# Spring Boot, Is it possible to add query parameters from Model attribute?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, modelattribute

Having a code like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/items", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ItemList getItems(@Valid @ModelAttribute ItemQuery listRequest) 
{
    responseItems.add(linkTo(methodOn(ItemController.class).getItems(listRequest.nextOwner())).withRel("next-owner"));
}
```

where `ItemQuery` keeps query properties like ownerId, offset, limit

Is it possible to add a link containing all the `ModelAttribute` properties as query parameters:

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651820/generate-links-with-additional-query-parameters-using-pagedresourcesassembler

Comment: I already checked it, but is not the same thing. My problem is that it doesn't  interpretate my Model properties to query parameters. In that case each parameter is annotated with RequestParameter.